# NullPointerException in Spring Framework (or what?)

Tags: java, spring, exception, servlets, servlet-filters

I have run into a very weird problem, and I have simply no idea, where to start. In our working application, one of our pages seems to fail kinda arbitrarily - that is, sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't.

The web application is running Java 6, Spring 2.5.6 and Hibernate 3.2.6. Furthermore, we are using Javax.servlet version 3.0 (might be relavant).

The problem becomes hard, because of a very limited stacktrace, which doesn't seem to involve any of our custom code (all our classes start with com.isworld.*).
The error occurs AFTER loading the page, when the form is submitted and the request is beeing processed. See stacktrace below:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:124)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is all there is to the stacktrace.

I do not expect any of you to come up with a solution to this problem, but hopefully, you can point me in some direction - I have no more ideas...

Comment: Can you also post the trace of the root cause? That would help to see what is going on there.

Comment: This is all there is... As proposed by Jerome, I am trying to wrap it, and get the full stack trace...

Comment: Which version of Spring you've been using?

Comment: OK, I know that one. It is 2.5.x.

Comment: @Hoof: Will you post your controller code? I reckon there is a problem.

Comment: I've the exact same issue, have you found the root cause?

Answer (score 4):

Spring Framework is open source, right? So lets have a look what is there at 583 line of `FrameworkServlet`...

What we can find there is following:

```
try {
    doService(request, response);
//omit a few catches...
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    failureCause = ex;
throw new NestedServletException("Request processing failed", ex); //line 583
}
```

So the exception comes from `FrameworkServlet.doService` method and it properly handled by Spring Framework. So lets have a look at the troublesome `doService` method...

`FrameworkServlet.doService` is abstract, but is implemented in `DispatcherServlet` that you most likely use in your project. Further it calls 'doDispatch' that dispatches handling of the request to the controller.

And my gut feeling tels me that the nasty `NPE` that we've been hunting here so persistently is hidden in your controller code...

Comment: Well, I can see why one might think that, however the problem does only occur in our production environment. A replicated environment running on local datastore and local webapp, works fine... But i'll take a look to see if anything is out of the ordinary...

Comment: Yeah, have a look at your code. It could be a data issues. I don't have any idea how do you access your database, but it could be an issues with some null columns or JPA/Hibernate entities.

Comment: But then this error should be persistent, and not random, as it is now. With the excact same data and code, the error only occurs in one server. Not in test nor locally. 

What basically happens is that a user can from a list select which items to be shown in the page. By submitting the page, the view is updated with onFormChange method, and really there is no magic going on... I will investigate further... :/

Comment: All I can do is to keep my fingers crossed, because without a crystal ball I can's say too much based on evidences you've provided ;)

Answer (score 2):

Set a breakpoint in your IDE to 'stop on throw' of NullPointerException (attach remote debugger if necessary)

Comment: I thought this as the self-evident next step, but apparently others didn't think so...

Answer (score 1):

I had a same symptom with @Hoof. But In my case It was in my development laptop. And after restarting tomcat root cause's Stacktrace is now being seen again.

Answer (score 0):

So, a NullPointerException happens during the execution of the servlet, and this exception is caught by the Spring framework which doesn't seem to bother displaying it.

You need to know where this NullPointerException happens.

Here are two possible ways to investigate further:

- Change FrameworkServlet.java in Spring sources so that the causing exception stack trace is displayed.
- Wrap your servlet with a try/catch to trap all exceptions, as in:

  try {
    ... your servlet code ...
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: I honestly doubt it is Spring fault. As you can see in my answer `FrameworkServlet` **does** bother to handle exceptions well by re-throwing them to the caller, so in my opinion adding another try/catch block is not a greatest idea.